# Smartgwt - How to turn off list grid automatic filtering

Tags: java, filter, smartgwt, listgrid

I set the listgrid's filterOnKeyPress to false and still it enters the FilterEditorSubmitHandler event whenever I type anything in the fields, I want to turn off automatic filtering.

According to the documentation: this event should only fire when I click the filter button or press enter or if the filter on key press is enabled.

Details:
SmartClient Version: v9.0_2013-07-03/LGPL Development Only 
Firefox 16.0

Comment: Can you post the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just want to know why the FilterEditorSubmit event is fired when the filter on key press is false

Comment: I asked you for the code as I'm not facing any such problem. If `filterOnKeyPress` is true, then `FilterEditorSubmitHandler` event is fired on every keypress. But if it's set to false, the event is fired only when I press enter.

Comment: Is there anyway to differentiate between when the FilterEditorSubmitHandler event is fired due to the filter button or enter key & due to the filter key press??

Comment: This is a new question. I would suggest you to post a new question or edit this post.